# Making sense of the proof : The set $\{s_n(x)=(2/\pi)^{1/2} \sin nx:n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is an orthonormal basis in $L^2[0,\pi]$- Rynne- Youngson

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The following theorem is from the book by Bryan P. Rynne, Martin A. Youngson - Linear Functional Analysis-Springer (2008)

**I am having trouble understanding the proof of theorem 3.56.**

the book's first edition is here https://books.google.co.zw/books?id=WVg4G_6gnXkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

**The author says he is just sketching it, could someone write the missing details? Specifically, explaining these 2 points:**

-Why do we need to approximate f, which is an $L^2[0,\pi]$ function with another $L^2[0,\pi]$ function ($f_\delta$). Is the author sugesting that the set of $\{f_\delta, f\in L^2[0,\pi]\}$ is dense in $L^2[0,\pi]$? Even if that is true I don't see the point of this construction

-Why is $f_\delta/\sin(x) \in L^2[0,\pi]$?(this is as written in the second edition,in the first edition it was $g_1$ instead of $f_\delta$, this seems to be a correction, but still) This doesn't seem correct. For instance if $f(x)=c=$constant ,then $f \in L^2[0,\pi]$ and $f_\delta/\sin(x)$ seems to go to $\infty$ at $x=\pi$, so if it is not even bounded how could it be in$ L^2[0,\pi]$? So is this an error? If it is not, how does this help with the proof?

Comment: This is a fine question, but it belongs on math.stackexchange.

Comment: @Nik Weaver I asked there first, but nobody is able to answer it, so I thought it required more experienced mathematicians